# Static moment of a solid problem.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How do I find the static moment in the comun part of the spheres $x^2+y^2+z^2<R^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2<2Rz$ with respect to the  plane $xy$. The density in any point of the solid is equal to the distance between that point and the plane $xy$. The problem here is I don't know what are the limits to put in the integral since the answer is $\frac{419}{180}R^5$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the static moment is. I've searched for it and it seems it has to be calculated with respect to a line. I answer because the question is about the integral limits.

We first pose the problem in cylindrical coordiates:

For the intersection of the spheres:

$\begin{cases}
  r^2+z^2=R^2\\
  r^2+(z-R)^2=R^2
\end{cases}$

$r_0=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}R$ discarding the negative as $r\ge0$ for cylindrical coordinates. For the spheres, we isolate $z$

$\begin{cases}
  z=\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\\
  z=R-\sqrt{R^2-r^2}
\end{cases}$

We've dropped the plus sign in the first and the minus sign in the second as the limiting surfaces are the upper one for the first sphere and the lower one for the second. The idea is integrate first for rings at some $r$ along $z$ from the surface of the second sphere to the surface of the first and then, integrate this resulting cylinders from $r=0$ to the intersection of the spheres.

The integral is:

$M_{xy}=\displaystyle\int_0^{(\sqrt{3}/2)R}\int_{R-\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}\int_0^{2\pi}f(z,r)\mathbb d\theta\mathbb dz\mathbb dr$

For some $f(z,r)$. Anyway, the factor $\pi$ has appeared for me in the hypothesis I studied for the moment and density.